# Is it appropriate to write in my LinkedIn profile "if you use LinkedIn like Facebook or post political content be I'll block you"?

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior, linkedin, networking, professional-development

I honestly don't remember the last time I saw a post on LinkedIn related to work. I'm sick and tired of it even though I barely navigate the front page. Not only I'm seeing narcissistic content constantly, but also lots of political propaganda, and while I'm politically active, I would love to not have these posts in a professional network where anything I would say can affect my professional connections. There's a place for that.

Examples:

- A woman gives birth, so she brags about her "new job" on LinkedIn
- A guy likes some European leader, so they post about how great they are on LinkedIn

And so on...

What do you think, guys. Is such an explicit message in the profile appropriate? Am I exaggerating? What would you do?

"If you use LinkedIn like Facebook for narcissistic purposes or post political content or like or share any of the former that it appears on my feed, I'll unfortunately have to block you. I use LinkedIn strictly for professional purposes"

Answer (score 18):

I can't see a positive outcome for the solution you proposed :

- Most of the people already behaving like LinkedIn is the new Facebook won't be notified of your profile change. This measure will thus have close to 0 impact for them.
- For the new contacts, the phrasing seems excessively aggressive. It will most likely act as a deterrant for recruiters/people working in the same field as you.

In the end, it all depends on your usage of LinkedIn. If you are considered influential and a lot of people follow you, or if you don't care about "scaring" away new contact requests, then sure, you can do it.

Otherwise, I personally think it's at best inefficient, at worst detrimental. I suggest you silently block annoying contacts, without putting a public PSA on your profile.

Note: if you absolutely want to notify people about how they are expected to behave professionally, do so in a professional manner. Something like "I use LinkedIn strictly for professional purposes, and tend to block non work related content" seems less aggressive

Answer (score 4):

> Is such an explicit message in the profile appropriate?

Sure, do whatever you want it's your profile. I got bored once and looked up some local people whose career I know, their profiles were a mix of pure fantasy and half truths.